# How to test class from void*

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

Suppose the following API :

```
CClassA(const CClassA& inCCA);
CClassA(void *inData);
```

How can we make sure nobody calls the void* constructor with a pointer to a `CClassA` object, i.e. detect invocations like `CClassA *instance; new CClassA(instance)`?

I'd like to check within the (void) constructor - and throw an error - if the API was used incorrectly, however `dynamic_cast` doesn't work on the raw void* as the compiler (at least clang does) complains about:
**'void is not a class'**

when testing `if (dynamic_cast<CClassA*>(inData) != NULL)`.

The following compiles - but does it make any sense, i.e. is it a valid and correct construct and will always evaluate correctly at runtime..?

```
if (dynamic_cast<CClassA*>( (CClassA*)inData ) != NULL)
```

Comment: You could add an overload for `CCLassA*` but that won't prevent people from passing any `void*` they want to, even if it points to a `CCLassA`. Guard against Murphy, not Machiavelli.

Comment: Can you avoid having a constructor from `void*`? It is going to cause all sorts of problems. Instead construct objects with a static member function for example.

Comment: @user3175411 Good point. It's an internal API so intention is early detection of errors, not dealing with malevolent API clients..

Comment: @tenfour unfortunately it's our serialization mechanism used widely throughout our code base and class hierarchy (the pattern above applies to a decent number of classes).

Comment: In general there's no way to tell whether a pointer really does point to an object of a certain type, because you can always arrange some bytes in memory so that they look like an object of that type.

Comment: `(CClassA*)inData` is equivalent to `static_cast<CClassA*>(inData)` (in this case). This pretty much only reinterprets the `void*` as the address of an object of type `CClassA*`. The succeeding `dynamic_cast` then has Undefined Behaviour if the object at `*inData` is not (originally) a `CClassA` if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a private constructor:

```
private:
    CClassA(CClassA *forbidden);
```

You won't be able to compile:

```
 error: calling a private constructor of class 'CClassA'
  CClassA *instance; new CClassA(instance);
```

Edit:

Since you mentioned the C++11 tag, you can delete it:

```
    CClassA(CClassA *forbidden) = delete;
```

This trigger a different compile-time error:

```
error: call to deleted constructor of 'CClassA'
  CClassA *instance; new CClassA(instance);
                     ^       ~~~~~~~~
note: 'CClassA' has been explicitly marked deleted here
  CClassA(CClassA *) = delete;
```

Comment: I missed the C++11 tag. Updated.

Comment: Does this really guard against `CClass A; void *ptr = (void *) &A; CClass B(ptr);`? To do so in all cases would require a clairvoyant compiler, AFAIU.

Comment: No, and there is no way to guard against that. You should not use void pointer in the interface in the first place.